# How to use @ResponseBody and @RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I reading spring 3.0.x reference  but I don't know how to use ,can you paste a full example?

Comment: There is enough info in the reference guide to make it work. If you have a specific question about it, then ask that. A broad "make it work for me" question is unlikely to make people respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@ResponseBody` if you want to return the content directly without any JSPs.

```
@RequestMapping("blubber")
@ResponseBody
public String blubber() {

    return "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do a search for

[spring @ResponseBody lang:java](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=spring+%40ResponseBody+lang%3Ajava&sbtn=Search)

and

[@RequestBody lang:java](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=%40RequestBody+lang%3Ajava&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code)

in Google Code Search, you can see numerous usages of `@ResponseBody` and `@RequestBody` there that might help you understand it better.